# Sweep array[,x,]*df in r

Tags: r

This works, but I really don't like using loops in r

```
  for(x in 1:nWeeks)
  {
    WSResultsres[,x] <-rowSums(SSresTrim[,x,]*LeafWeights);
  }
```

SSres is an array [1:55470,1:141,1:20] and

```
str(SSresTrim)
num [1:55470, 1:141, 1:20] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

LeafWeights is a df of num [1:55470,1:20]

I'm fine doing a 2 step and multiplying them first, but when I do:

```
WSResultsres<-sweep(SSresTrim,c(1,3),LeafWeights,'*')
```

I get

```
Error in FUN(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)), ...) : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Expanding LeafWeights to an array and do an element wise multiplication works and is much faster than the loop, but feels inelegant.

```
mLeafWeights<-as.matrix(LeafWeights)
dimnames(mLeafWeights) <- NULL
LeafWeightsArray <- array(mLeafWeights, 
dim=c(nrow(LeafWeights),nWeeks,ncol(LeafWeights))); 
WSResultsres<-SSresTrim*LeafWeightsArray
#and then do a sum on dim=2
```

Does anyone have something classier?  Thanks
-Rick

Comment: And `sweep(SSresTrim, c(1,3), as.matrix(LeafWeights), '*')` ?

Comment: I played with that a bit, transforming it to a as.martix & as.matrix.numeric and then setting dimnames(LeafWeights)<-NULL without any luck. I still got the same thing... At least it is good to hear that someone else had the same thoughts.